# determinating the signature of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

As as part of my course in Lie groups,
I need some help to determine the signature of the form $B(x,y) = $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ x_iy_{n+1-i}$

More than anything, I would like to understand how to determine a signature of such forms, rather than the plain answer.

thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have a typo, what should $y_n + 1 - i$ be? Should it be $y_{n+1-i}$ and then the sum should really start at $i=1$ instead of $0$?

Comment: exactly what i ment, my bad. thanks for the correction

Comment: not sure how to lower-case the rest of y's index.. srry

Comment: I adjusted the TeX for the subscript...

Answer (score 0):

The associated quadratic form has a slightly different nature depending on the parity of $n$. For $n$ odd, it is $x_1x_n+x_2x_{n-1}+\ldots+x_{{n+1\over 2}}^2$, while for $n$ even there is no pure square term.

The summands $x_ix_j$ with $i\not=j$ are "hyperbolic pairs", and have signatures $(1,-1)$. The pure square term, for $n$ odd, has signature $(1,0)$. Add them up.

(There are many supporting exercises one could do here... in the direction of "geometric algebra", and Sylvester's Inertia Theorem, but I don't know your context.)